# How to use a macro in a function call?

Tags: c, function, macros

I dont't understand why this macro, used in a function call is not working.

```
#define MAX 255;
printf("max value %d", MAX);
```

but this is

```
#define MAX 255;
int m = MAX;
printf("max value %d", m);
```

Isn't the preprocessor substituting the values before
compiling. Why is he complaining ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is the semicolon `;`. Remove it:

```
#define MAX 255
```

Otherwise the two code samples expand as follows:

```
printf("max value %d", 255;);
```

and

```
int m = 255;;
printf("max value %d", m);
```

In the second case it results in an innocuous empty statement. In the first the program is ill-formed.

Remember that macro definitions are *not* statements. They are directives to the preprocessor that instruct on how to do token substitution.

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("max value %d", 255;);
```

is invalid syntax.

```
int m = 255;;
printf("max value %d", m);
```

is legal.